# Django: Unknown command: 'loadcsv'

Tags: python, django, csv, export-to-csv

I get the error Unknown command: 'loadcsv'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage. when trying:

```
python manage.py loadcsv --csv reviews/managment/commands/WebDevWithDjangoData.csv
```

why I am getting this error?

[image]

I running this code in the correct folder seems like loadcsv is not working Do i need to install something to run loadcsv?

Comment: The problem was typo in mangment instead of management